# Calculate time difference between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I currently have a database in the following format

```
ID  |  DateTime             |  PID   |  TIU
1   |  2013-11-18 00:15:00  |  1551  |  1005
2   |  2013-11-18 00:16:03  |  1551  |  1885
3   |  2013-11-18 00:16:30  |  9110  |  75527
4   |  2013-11-18 00:22:01  |  1022  |  75
5   |  2013-11-18 00:22:09  |  1019  |  1311
6   |  2013-11-18 00:23:52  |  1022  |  89
7   |  2013-11-18 00:24:19  |  1300  |  44433
8   |  2013-11-18 00:38:57  |  9445  |  2010
```

I have a scenario where I need to identify where there are gaps in processes more than 5 minutes by using the `DateTime` column.

An example of what I am trying to achieve is:

```
ID  |  DateTime             |  PID   |  TIU
3   |  2013-11-18 00:16:30  |  9110  |  75527
4   |  2013-11-18 00:22:01  |  1022  |  75
7   |  2013-11-18 00:24:50  |  1300  |  44433
8   |  2013-11-18 00:38:57  |  9445  |  2010
```

ID3 is the last row before a 6 minute 1 second gap, ID4 is the next row after it.
ID7 is the last row before a 14 minute 7 second gap, ID8 is the next record available.

I am trying to do this in SQL, however if needs be I can do this in C# to process instead.

I have tried a number of inner joins, however the table is over 3 million rows so performance suffers greatly.

Comment: While set-based solutions are lovely and make SQL as powerful as it is, this may require an iterative solution. That said, it can still be done (and probably better) in SQL. If you're trying to find these gaps between this row and the next, a cursor and an insert to a temp table or a CTE is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a CTE solution but, as has been indicated, this may not always perform well - because we're having to compute functions against the `DateTime` column, most indexes will be useless:

```
declare @t table (ID int not null,[DateTime] datetime not null,
                  PID int not null,TIU int not null)
insert into @t(ID,[DateTime],PID,TIU) values
(1,'2013-11-18 00:15:00',1551,1005  ),
(2,'2013-11-18 00:16:03',1551,1885  ),
(3,'2013-11-18 00:16:30',9110,75527 ),
(4,'2013-11-18 00:22:01',1022,75    ),
(5,'2013-11-18 00:22:09',1019,1311  ),
(6,'2013-11-18 00:23:52',1022,89    ),
(7,'2013-11-18 00:24:19',1300,44433 ),
(8,'2013-11-18 00:38:57',9445,2010  )

;With Islands as (
    select ID as MinID,[DateTime],ID as RecID from @t t1
    where not exists
        (select * from @t t2
            where t2.ID < t1.ID and --Or by date, if needed
                    --Use 300 seconds to avoid most transition issues
            DATEDIFF(second,t2.[DateTime],t1.[DateTime]) < 300
        )
    union all
    select i.MinID,t2.[DateTime],t2.ID
    from Islands i
        inner join
        @t t2
            on
                i.RecID < t2.ID and
                DATEDIFF(second,i.[DateTime],t2.[DateTime]) < 300
), Ends as (
    select MinID,MAX(RecID) as MaxID from Islands group by MinID
)
select * from @t t
where exists(select * from Ends e where e.MinID = t.ID or e.MaxID = t.ID)
```

This also returns a row for ID 1, since that row has no preceding row within 5 minutes of it - but that should be easy enough to exclude in the final select, if needed.

I've assumed we can use `ID` as a proxy for increasing dates - that if for two rows, the `ID` is higher in the second row, then the `DateTime` will also be later.

---

[`Islands`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is a recursive CTE. The top half (the anchor) just selects rows which do not have any preceding row within 5 minutes of themselves. We select the `ID` twice for those rows and also keep the `DateTime` around.

In the recursive portion, we try to find a new row from the table that can be "added on" to an existing `Islands` row - based on this new row being no more than 5 minutes later than the current end-point of the island.

Once the recursion is complete, we then exclude the intermediate rows that the CTE produces. E.g. for the "4" island, it generated the following rows:

```
4,00:22:01,4
4,00:22:09,5
4,00:23:52,6
4,00:24:19,7
```

And all that we care about is that final row where we've identified an "island" of time from ID 4 to ID 7 - that's what the second CTE (`Ends`) is finding for us.

Comment: This looks really promising, the only question I have really is regarding the `INSERT INTO` statement to start with. Is there a way to use data already in the table as there are 3mil+ rows which I need to check against.

Comment: @lethalMango - yes, the top part of the script was just to set up the data so that my answer gives a complete script that you (or anyone) can run in SSMS. To use your table, you'd skip the top section and just replace all references to `@t` with your real table.